# Python dataframe Creating new key from columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which is like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Country': ['GER', 'ITA'],
'2000': ['1','4'],
'2001': ['2','5'],
'2002': ['3','6'],
 })
```

which means the data are like

```
   Country 2000 2001 2002
 0 GER     1    2    3
 1 ITA     4    5    6
```

and I want to take the values of the columns and create a new dataframe where these values are part of the key

```
   Country Year  Value
 0 GER     2000  1
 1 GER     2001  2     
 2 GER     2003  3     
 3 ITA     2000  4 .....
```

how can I can do something like this?

Comment: For your specific case `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Country'], value_name='Value', var_name='Year')`

Comment: Wow thanks! Write it as an answer to upvote you

Comment: I've linked to an older question that asks a similar operation, thank you. :)